# Cross-platform plurals - embedding resource string in another string in iOS

Tags: ios

I would like to generate i18n plural files for Android and iOS from common data sheet. I found that [twine](https://github.com/mobiata/twine) can do it for me. Unfortunately [twine does not support plurals](https://github.com/mobiata/twine/issues/46). One has suggested to embed into plural files resource strings. In Android it would look like this:

```
    <plurals name="cool_things">
      <item quantity="one">@string/cool_things_one</item>
      <item quantity="other">@string/cool_things_other</item>
    </plurals>
```

In this way plural file can use strings generated by twine. Is it possible to embed in the same way strings from Localizable.strings to Localizable.stringsdict? If not, how do you solve cross-platform i18n of plurals?